# Why the parameter doesn't change in the class constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, default-arguments

Here it is my code. I don't get it why it doesn't print 3, even though in the class constructor param1 becomes 3.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{

    int valoare;
public:

    A(int param1 = 3):valoare(param1){}
    int getValoare(){return this -> valoare;}
};

int main()
{

    A vector[] = {*(new A(3)), *(new A(4)), *(new A(5)), *(new A(6))};
    cout << vector[2].getValoare();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `param1` becomes `3` only if you do not provide an argument, which you actually do. For `vector[2]`, this argument is `5`.

Comment: You have immediate memory leaks! Do you perhaps come from a Java or C# background where `new` must be used to create new objects? In C++ you don't need that. Doing e.g. `A(3)` without `new` is perfectly fine.

Comment: As for your question, stop just guessing about what things mean in C++, and [get a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to learn properly.

Comment: `vector[2]` is initialised using `*(new A(5))` which gives its `valoare` member the value `5`.     And also causes a memory leak - avoid the leak by initialising with `A(5)`.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to read about default arguments: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments

When you specify an argument for a function with a defualt argument it overrides that default value. Thus, your code will print out 5.

As a side note, your code has a memory leak becuase you allocated memory with the `new` keyword and never deleted it. You should change the declaration of your Vector, that is, allocate memory on the stack like follows:

```
Vector = {A(3), A(4), A(5), A(6)}
```

Answer (score 2):

The element at index 2 in the vector was constructed as `A(5)`, so it's value ("valoare") is 5. The `= 3` in the function definition is a [default argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) - which is used if you don't specify one yourself. So if you were to write:

```
std::cout << A().getValoare();
```

that would print `3`.

But a few more observations are in order:

1. Prefer English-language names. `valoare` means "value" in some Latin or European language, right? Romanian perhaps? But - people who don't speak that language won't know that. Since you have to know English to program anyways, that's a safe choice for names.
2. Try not to use names for variables which are also names of classes in a different namespace. For example, your `vector` has the same name as `std::vector`, a class, or rather a class template, in the standard library. Try `vec` or `my_vector` or something else that's more distinctive.
3. You're leaking memory! Why are you using `new` to create values? Just use the construct, i.e.

   ```
   A vector[] = { A(3), A(4), A(5), A(6) };
   ```

   is just fine.
4. More generally, you should [avoid calling `new` and `delete` explicitly](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-newdelete), and instead prefer [RAII-style](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) classes - which allocate on construction and deallocate on destruction. The simplest thing to do is to switch to using [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one?s=1%7C1340.1263)

Answer (score 1):

> Why the parameter doesn't change in the class constructor?

It doesn't print the value `3` because you're giving it another value.

from *[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments)*:

> Default arguments are used in place of the missing trailing arguments in a function call:
>
> ```
> void point(int x = 3, int y = 4);
>
> point(1,2); // calls point(1,2)
> point(1);   // calls point(1,4)
> point();    // calls point(3,4)
> ```